# Why is my ASP.NET Core for dotnet 5 Web API route working with browser but not working with Postman

Tags: .net, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.Net 5.0 for learning purpose. It is working with my browser but not working on my postman. Although I followed the whole process according to the tutorial.

I searched and found many solution on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) but they are not helpful for me.

[image]

Comment: What is exactly the problem you're stuck on? Show us your code, Postman setup, requests, responses, error messages. We can't answer this post which is not even a question since there's no "?" in your post.

Comment: What type of Web Security method you are using? Maybe when you are trying to connect through you are not giving the correct URL or passing the correct parameters. There are several questions that come here.

Comment: Screenshots aren't a problem description, unless you ask about graphics. You can do more or less the same things Postman does by opening your browser's Developer Tools (typically with F12) and inspecting the call in the `Network` tab. You'll find the request headers, payload *and* SSL settings. What does the `Network` tab show about your request? Have you replicated all headers? Is SSL working?

Comment: Does your browser display a certificate warning as well? In that case, the safest option when connecting to a *local* web site using a self-signed certificate, is to trust that certificate, not disable SSL verification

Comment: Since you use the `asp.net-core` tag, did you [trust the development certificate when you installed .NET Core?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable `SSL certificate verification`

File -> Settings -> General -> SSL certificate verification

[image]

Comment: It's far safer to trust the development certificate than disable verification. When someone doesn't know about certificates it's quite likely they'll forget to turn verification back on after testing